# SQL Server - How calculate # of entities to hit 80% of sum total?

Tags: sql, sql-server, percentage

I have a list of companies, their industry, and their annual revenue.

I need to partition the list by industry and figure out how many companies in each industry it takes to account for 80% of the industry's total revenue.

I can run the partition, I can figure out what 80% of each industry's revenue is, but I have zero idea how to figure out how many companies it takes to hit 80%.  My only idea is to pull a list for each industry, sort revenue high to low, and sum down until I hit the 80% number.

Are there any built-in functions or clever approaches that can help me here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would use window functions:

```
select industry, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             sum(revenue) over (partition by industry order by revenue desc) as running_revenue,
             sum(revenue) over (partition by industry) as total_revenue
      from t
     ) t
where running_revenue - revenue < 0.8 * total_revenue
group by industry;
```

The `where` includes all companies up to the first that passes the 80% threshold.

There are other functions such as `ntile()` and `percentile()` that can be used.  I find it simplest to do the calculation directly using `sum()`.

Comment: oh wow this is brilliant!  thanks so much, I'm gonna give it a shot now

Comment: Worked like an absolute charm, very elegant solution and you've saved me a ton of time.  Thanks for the time Gordon, you're an absolute wizard